# Custom download manager

Tags: android, download, custom-component

I need to make a custom download manager as I am using android 2.2 version and google has given download manager api from android 2.3 version.

Comment: Standard browsers use their own activity and corresponding code in order to display the list of downloading files. But I didn't see anyone released their code on github or other open source repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to form http requests with your download file url. Also go through http request and response header where you have options to request from how many bites to end you want to download. Also in response you have how many bytes downloaded so far like that. You also have to implement some broadcast receiver like wifi changed and device shutdown and reboot. In those places you have to write some info like how many bytes downloaded so far, what is url you are downloading from and how many are still pending and resume them after reboot. If you don't understand, give your mail I will send some code. Above one is the way I did in past, I too am a beginner like you.

Comment: Hi buddy  I am facing the same problem here is my mail id.
spvakharia3@yahoo.co.in ..
will you please send code me for custom android DownloadManager

Comment: Hi, would you please share me the code? I am frustrated with this problem.... nucleus302@gmail.com